# Creating setup.py for existing project structure

Tags: python, setuptools

I started working on a project with the following folder structure where each top folder lives in a separate repository:

```
project-api/
  source/
     module1.py
     module2.py
project-core/
  source/
     module3.py
     module4.py
```

I would like to `pip install -e` and be able to do:

```
from api.module1 import function1
from core.module3 import function3
```

without changing the folder structure (fixed by the project).

**Question**: How can I create the corresponding(s) `setup.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with `pip install -e` because option `-e` "installs" packages in development/editable mode. It doesn't actually install anything but creates a link that allows Python to import modules directly from the development directory. Unfortunately in your case that impossible — directories `project-core` and `project-api` contain forbidden character in their name (`-`) — these directories cannot be made importable in-place.

But `pip install .` could be made to install top-level packages `api` and `core` from these directories. First you have to add `__init__.py`:

```
touch project-api/source/__init__.py
touch project-core/source/__init__.py
```

And the following `setup.py` do the rest:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='example',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='Example',
    packages=['api', 'core'],
    package_dir={
        'api': 'project-api/source',
        'core': 'project-core/source',
    }
)
```

Run `pip install .` and you're done. Execute `import api, core` in Python.

PS. If you can create symlinks at the root:

```
ln -s project-api/source api
ln -s project-core/source core
```

you can use `pip install -e .`